# How to convert gradle dependencies to maven in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gradle, integration-testing

I am trying to create an Integration Test, but as the example is created for Gradle, I tried to add them as dependency, but could not make it work.

So, how can I translate the following gradle (with dependencies and any other needed parts) ? I look at on the web, but could not find any tool, etc :(

Note: The GitHub link of the example is on https://github.com/arhohuttunen/spring-boot-test-examples/blob/main/spring-boot-integration-testing/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.arhohuttunen'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'
targetCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.javamoney:moneta:1.4.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    testImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.10.0'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:postgresql'
    testRuntimeOnly 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.testcontainers:testcontainers-bom:1.17.6"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a tool to generate a `pom.xml` from a `build.gradle`(`gradle init` command can generate a build.gradle from a pom.xml). I was able to manually create the below pom.xml. `mvn test` runs 6 tests successfully

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.arhohuttunen</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-integration-testing</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-integration-testing</name>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <okhttp.version>4.10.0</okhttp.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.17.6</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javamoney</groupId>
            <artifactId>moneta</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
            <version>${okhttp.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>${okhttp.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```